# python 3.1 boolean check with for loop

Tags: python

How can I add a Boolean check to a for loop? I was trying something like this:

```
for i in range (0, someNumber) and keepGoing == True
```

It is giving me the error 'bool' object is not iterable. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This isn't a for loop like in C; what you're doing here is creating a range object and iterating over each element in it (naming it "i") in the process. In C, you can have multiple checks during an iteration of a loop, but in Python you iterate over iterable objects such as lists or tuples.

```
for i in range(0, someNumber):
    if keepGoing:
        # Code
```

Basically, you can't set a flag to stop the loop, because the "loop" is going to iterate over the entire range object. The only way to add a "stop flag" is to `break` out of the loop.

```
for i in range(0, someNumber):
    if not keepGoing:
        break
    else:
        # Code
```

or even

```
for i in range(0, someNumber):
    if not keepGoing:
        break
    # Code
```

Comment: You may want to add `else: break` to that as well.

Comment: @Pinsickle: No problem. If my answer solved your problem, click the big checkbox to accept it as the answer.

Comment: @Zeke Thought I'd let you know you solved my problem twice. I was messing with Python back in 2010 for a school project and haven't really used it again since then. Fast forward a year and I had student in another teaching assistant's class come to me with a similar problem. I Google the problem and I find this. I thought it was pretty funny.